# Form validation in another route Flask

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I have a flask wtform. I am able to validate the form in a route where it is instantiated. But I want to validate it from another route. Without using session variable, Is there any other way by which I can access the form object from the other route?

**form_class.py**

```
class Fruit ( Form):
    Fruit = SelectField ( choices = [ ( 0,"Select Fruit"), ( 1,'Apple'), (2,'Grape'), (3,'Orange') ], coerce = int, id="Fruit", validators = [Required()])
```

**views.py**:

```
@app.route('/fruit',  methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def fruit():
    form = Fruit()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
       return render_template("output.html")
    return render_template("name.html", form = form)
```

**name.html**

```
<form action="" method="POST">
      {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
      {{form.Fruit}}
      {{form.Fruit.errors}}
      <input type = "submit">
</form>
```

The above code works completely fine. But I want to do something like the below:

```
@app.route('/fruit')
def fruit():
    form = Fruit()
    '''if form.validate_on_submit():
       return render_template("output.html")'''
    return render_template("name.html", form = form)

@app.route('/fruit_submit', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def fruit_submit():
    print request.form
    if form.validate_on_submit():
       return render_template("output.html")
```

I am getting the following error upon trying the above code.

```
NameError: global name 'form' is not defined
```

Comment: Each request is unique. A variable defined as part of one doesn't exist in another. Also, that isn't how scope works in Python. A variable defined in one function isn't available inside another, non-nested function. Simply add `form = Fruit()` to `fruit_submit` and you'll be all set.

Comment: `form = Fruit()` redefine in `fruit_submit` ?? @dirn

Comment: You aren't redefining anything. `form` isn't defined in `fruit_submit`. That's [what `NameError` means](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#NameError). If you want to use something named `form` inside `fruit_submit`, you need to define it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call the Fruit class with request.form

```
@app.route('/fruit_submit', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def fruit_submit():
    print Fruit(request.form)
    if Fruit(request.form).validate_on_submit():
       return render_template("output.html")
```

Comment: It should be `Fruit(request.form).validate_on_submit()`. Please edit it. I will accept the answer. Thank you.